# windows phone phonegap application performance issue?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-mobile

Have developed the app for android using phonegap everything is perfect and ported it into windows the performance is too slow and takes time to form the html page etc in windows phone any solutions to improve it?